Feasibility of entropy at zero temperature
I remember a college lecturer of mine once gave me this equation of entropy during one of his lectures on thermodynamics:
$$
\begin{align*}
\Delta{S} = \frac{ d {Q} }{T} \\
\end{align*}
$$
I found out that this entropy equation appears in reversible process, for instance, in a Carnot engine.
I wonder what would physically occur at absolute zero temperature, since mathematically, plugging $T = 0 K$ into the above equation would yield division by zero. Does this mean that reversible thermodynamic process cannot occur at zero Kelvin?

The third law of thermodynamics

The first and most important part to this question is the link By Symmetry points out in the comments, which includes the following:

The third law is equivalent to the statement that
It is impossible by any procedure, no matter how idealized, to reduce the temperature of any closed system to zero temperature in a finite number of finite operations.

So right away we must recognize that any talk of operations occurring at absolute zero is simply an academic exercise in math, not something which bears any relevance to the world.  As physics is concerned with predictive statements about the world, there's no guarantee that there's any deeper meaning to be had by answering the question.  It's merely a differential equation expression, nothing more, with no physical meaning.
We can consider the limit as T approaches zero:

The third law of thermodynamics states that the entropy of a closed system at thermodynamic equilibrium approaches a constant value when its temperature approaches absolute zero.

But that isn't what you're asking.
Even diving into statistical mechanics, the concept of "what happens at absolute zero" just isn't a concern.  Several of the common statistical mechanics constructions use temperature as an external control parameter, and they always use it in a denominator, so they'd be a non-starter.  The microcanonical ensemble approach uses energy instead, and defines temperature as a derived value, two of them in fact: $\frac 1 T_v=\frac{dS_v}{dE}$ and $\frac 1 T_s=\frac{dS_s}{dE}$.  But in both case, the division remains.
So, in the end, the answer to your question is "thermodynamics is not the correct language to describe what happens in these conditions."  Every handling of temperature in the field that I can find simply excludes $T=0$ from the domain of temperatures.

After spending some time looking for any loophole I could to give a more satisfying answer than this, I find the question really starts to look like a paradox more than anything.  Part way through, it started to feel like trying to answer "How many stones can a bag carry if the bag can carry more than it can carry."  It's something that can be phrased, just not something which one can really do anything about.
